# Select two cells and subtract?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Looking to find out how I would go about this in Excel:

Select two  cells
Subtract the highest from the lowest
Display in a specific cell

I searched but can't find the answer :(

i.e. Select cell A1 (1000) and then select cell A2 (900) -> result displayed in cell A5 = 100

Does this make sense?

Comment: Try this: `=IF(A1>A2, A1-A2, A2-A1)`

Comment: More about the [IF() function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) here.

Comment: Thanks for the two replies.  I need to work out how I can get it to work out the cells which the user has selected though.

Comment: That's probably not hard, either.  If you want some help from people here, please explain clearly how the user selects the cells.  Is there a drop down list? Does the user just type numbers into two cells? Are they limited to a certain range of columns or rows?

Comment: Thanks - I actually managed to do it a far better way than selecting two cells as it turned out there was a lot more data than I thought.

Answer (score 2):

No need to check which is greater, you can simply subtract one from the other, then take the absolute value of the result:

```
=ABS(A1-A2)
```

If you would still prefer to check which is greater, you can use `IF`:

```
=IF(A1>A2, A1-A2, A2-A1)
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Bandersnatch points out, it is a very simple formula:

```
  =IF(A1>A2,A1-A2,A2-A1)
```

Where A1 and A2 are the comparison cells. Simply place this formula in the "display" cell.

The formula breaks down as:

- A1>A2 -- the comparison to make.
- A1-A2 -- the value to display if true (A1 is larger than A2).
- A2-A1 -- the value to display if false (A1 is not larger than A2).